# change a word in armature bones names with a script

Tags: scripting, armature

I have an armature with some of it's bones names has a prefix like "_cloth_bone-name" . i want to change it to "[cloth]bone-name" , I can do a simple rename but there is a lot of these so I tried to look at some scripts online and found this , but it doesn't seem to do any thing.

````
import bpy
context = bpy.context
obj = context.object

namelist = [


("_cloth_","[cloth]")

]

for name, newname in namelist:
    # get the pose bone with name
    pb = obj.pose.bones.get(name)
    # continue if no bone of that name
    if pb is None:
        continue
    # rename
    pb.name = newname 

 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Rename bones

```
# "_x_y" to [x]y"

import bpy

for bone in bpy.context.object.data.bones:
    name = bone.name
    i = name.find("_")
    if i != -1:
        name = name[ : i] + "[" + name[i + 1 : ]
        i = name.find("_")
        if i != -1:
            name = name[ : i] + "]" + name[i + 1 : ]
            bone.name = name
```